# Web2py SQLTABLE data style setting

Tags: web2py

In my application I am using a SQLTABLE to display contents. I have to specify some css styles to this table data. 
Please let me know how can I set the styles to SQLTABLE data.

example:

```
#percengate datatype: decimal(5,2)
rows = db().select(db.t_tax.id,db.t_tax.percentage)
db.t_tax.percentage.represent = lambda r,v: str(v.percentage)+'%'
columns = ['t_tax.id','t_tax.percentage']
headers = {
    't_tax.id':{'label':T('id'),
    'class':'', #class name of the header
    'width':'', #width in pixels or %
    'truncate': 50, #truncate the content to...
    'selected': False #agregate class selected to this column
    },
    't_tax.percentage':{'label':T('Tax'),
    'class':'', #class name of the header
    'width':'', #width in pixels or %
    'truncate': 50, #truncate the content to...
    'selected': False #agregate class selected to this column
    }
}
table = SQLTABLE(rows,columns=columns,headers=headers,_width='100%',_class='datatable')
```

in this table I want to right align the Percentage column data. Right now it is showing as a normal string(10.00%,20.00%) left aligned. I couldnt find any option to specify alignment only to percetage column.

I would greatly appreciate any comments.

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding the CSS styles you need to set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you creating the SQLTABLE directly?

Have you tried:

```
x = SQLTABLE(rows, ..., _id='my-sqltable')
```

Then you can use `#my-sqltable` as the first part of your selector. For example, to highlight every other row:

```
#my-sqltable tr:nth-child(odd) td { background: gray; }
```

There is no way to pass specific styles to different columns/cells in the sql-table. Normally you would do `x = SQLTABLE(..., _style=...)` but even then, there would be no simple way to target the column you want.

You can however create a class that will be attached to a given column using the "class" parameter for the "headers" keyword. Set class to "some-class" and check the generated markup -- you should see that you have th.some-class as well as td.some-class. You can use the class to target the element you want styled. Again, there is no way with SQLTABLEs to attach "style" attributes to the generated TD nodes.

You might be able to use the "extracolumns" and set the content with a lambda function (something like `{'content': lambda row: DIV(row.some_val, _style='text-align: right'), ...}`) which will wrap the content in a DIV and allow you to right align it, but really the classes are much easier. You might need to do something like this to make your SQLTABLE look the same without relying on an external stylesheet... I'm just not sure it will work.

If you have concerns about updating your css separately or having your code be more modular, you could always pass a STYLE element to the view, or just create a `<style>...</style>` enclosure directly in the view that uses the style. While it's technically "invalid" to place the style tag outside of the head element in HTML4x/XHTML, it will still parse. Also, in HTML5, this is totally 100% valid to do.

Anyawy, I hope I've answered your question. I highly recommend just using a class -- could just be `.align-right  { text-align: right }` in your base css, as this class can then be used on any number of things. This is already supported by the code!

If none of these options is acceptable, I'm afraid you'll have to dig in and write your own custom TABLE class. You can subclass SQLTABLE perhaps and figure out a good way to add style options to data columns within your TABLE... I **still** think classes are better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is useful for me. But I just want to know is there any direct method to specify styles while describing the SQLTABLE. I have edited my question. Please let me know if there is any settings inside SQLTABLE function, instead of specify the styles seperatly.

Comment: Tanks for this nice reply. 'Set class to "some-class" and check the generated markup -- you should see that you have th.some-class as well as td.some-class'. This is what I was looking. I thought the header class is only for heading th. Kasapo thank you once again for this great reply.

Comment: @Pradeeshnarayan Ya, it isn't exactly the most intuitive part of web2py. Glad I was able to help!